# how to fix the error If you click next, its data formattedDate should go?

Tags: android, api, calendar

If next button is clicked, its data should go to formattedDate I have tried several times and it keeps giving me an error.[image]

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            textView.setText(formattedDate);
            post.recipe_time = formattedDate;
        }
    });
```

this formattedDate error how to clear

```
       private void requestHomeData2() {
            ApiInterface apiInterface = 
         RestAdapter.createAPI(sharedPref.getApiUrl());
            callbackCall2 = 
        apiInterface.getDate(formattedDate,AppConfig.REST_API_KEY);
        this.callbackCall2.enqueue(new Callback<Callbackdate>() {
                public void onResponse(Call<Callbackdate> call, 
 Response<Callbackdate> response) {
                    Callbackdate responseHome = response.body();
                    if (responseHome == null || !responseHome.status.equals("ok")) {
                        onFailRequest();
                        return;
                    }
                    displayData2(responseHome);
                    swipeProgress(false);
                    lyt_main_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
    
                public void onFailure(Call<Callbackdate> call, Throwable th) {
                    Log.e("onFailure", th.getMessage());
                    if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                        onFailRequest();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please share error.

Comment: @DenistHeMenAce D:\apk\update kalvi\Tamilcalender\app\src\main\java\com\Tamiltv\newspaper\fragments\FragmentHome.java:225: error: cannot find symbol
        callbackCall2 = apiInterface.getDate(formattedDate,AppConfig.REST_API_KEY);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable formattedDate
  location: class FragmentHome

Comment: variable formattedDate is outside the scope of method requestHomeData2

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `String formattedDate` variable as global variable and initialize it like `String formattedDate = ""`, then assign value `formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());` in your next button click and then invoke `requestHomeData2` wherever you need it.

Comment: i wll try String formattedDate assign error clear but next click button data not pass requestHomeData2 image https://ibb.co/Pw0ngzB

Comment: You mean to say that, on the next button click, requestHomeData2 is not getting the value of formattedDate variable, am I right?